# VBA Worksheet_Change unables me to work on other Files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to check whatever I write in a given range of sheet1 and transfer it to sheet2 with modification or not depending on the value.
The macro itself works fine.

**My Problem:**
I have sheet1 opened, a cell is selected but I am not writing anything. If I open an other file and do any change in this second file, then Excel kind of freezes. Feels like Screenupdating went to False. There is no update of what I do in any File, or when I change sheets or selection, or even if I select an other menu in the ribbon. If I select File, the whole window goes grey.
It only occurs when sheet1 is activated in the first File. Otherwise (meaning for example that I work on sheet2 and then switch to an other Excel File), everything is ok.

I tried to put some Msgboxes in my macro to see if it was somehow triggered. But no MsgBox showed up.

I commented the screenUpdating / EnableEvents / Calculation lines to ensure that there was no way for Excel to freeze because of it. Problem is still here.

I have some macros firing up at the opening and closing of my File, but I don't believe they can interfere in my problem. You can have a look at my code. I believe it is basic, maby not perfect, but I don't see how it can bring such an issue.

If anyone has a solution, or a link to a post already solved that I didn't find, thank you for sharing it.

Thank you guys for your help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7:NJ42")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
        For Each Zelle In Target
            If UCase(Zelle.Value) = "U" Or UCase(Zelle.Value) = "ÜA" Or UCase(Zelle.Value) = "AF" Then
                Column = Zelle.Column
                Linie = Zelle.Row
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Linie, Column).Value = "A"
            ElseIf UCase(Zelle.Value) <> "UW" Then
                Column = Zelle.Column
                Linie = Zelle.Row
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Linie, Column).Value = Zelle
            End If
        Next
        
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.Calculate
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I basically recreated the whole file, sheet after sheet, macro after macro. This new File is doing the exact same thing as the previous one, contains the exact same data, formulas and formatting... And it works!!!

N.B.: When I copied the sheets themselves, it didn't work. I had to copy paste my data and formatting on fresh Sheets.

The issue is gone, somehow.

Possibilities that I see at the moment are:

- A colleague did a change in the Excel that made it buggy. But the only thing there are able to change are things within the sheets themselves.
- An Option in Excel was on (or off) and caused the problem
- Something else...

Still, if someone knows where this could come from, I stay opened to any suggestion. This could help people not having to recreate a whole complex Excel File for nothing.

Answer (score -1):

### Worksheet Change Failing

- Use `turnOnSettings` to make Excel 'fully functional'.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const ProcName As String = "Worksheet_Change"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7:NJ42")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
        Dim Zelle As Range
        Dim Spalte As Long
        Dim Linie As Long
        
        For Each Zelle In Target.Cells
            If UCase(Zelle.Value) = "U" Or UCase(Zelle.Value) = "ÜA" _
                    Or UCase(Zelle.Value) = "AF" Then
                Spalte = Zelle.Column
                Linie = Zelle.Row
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Linie, Spalte).Value = "A"
            ElseIf UCase(Zelle.Value) <> "UW" Then
                Spalte = Zelle.Column
                Linie = Zelle.Row
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Linie, Spalte).Value = Zelle.Value
            End If
        Next Zelle

SafeExit:
        On Error GoTo FatalError
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.Calculate
    End If
    
ProcExit:
    
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

FatalError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Fatal Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    MsgBox "Your safe exit has been compromised.", vbCritical, "Fatal Error"
    turnOnSettings
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub

Sub turnOnSettings()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, even with your code I had the same issue. There was no trigger of any safe exits, or at least no MsgBox popping up... I will recreate my file step by step from a proper, clean file and see if I have the same issue and at what point.

Comment: N.B.: I really like the way you code your safe exits. I never found mine to be well written and rarely bother including any. Thanks for the nice example!